# How to run two different applications simultaneously in same port with same Machine in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to run two different applications (i.e:Two different Microservices) running in same port(eg:in port 3000).I have implemented concepts like creating multiple distro's in ubuntu.But simultaneously that was not working with same ports.Adding to this,I have created different NIC to run in same port.That was also not working.Please,suggest some concepts to implement it.

Comment: The technology you are looking for is likely called a reverse proxy. There are hundreds (if not thousands) of questions here on SF regarding this technology. https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/reverse-proxy . To clarify, 2 services cannot exist on the same IP:Port combination at the same time, you need something to listen on the IP:Port and pass connections to the correct backend (micro) service.

Comment: Adding to the comment above, if the services are HTTP endpoints, you can enable "Virtual Hosting" of your web server that exposes these endpoints (assuming they are both exposed from the same web server). With Virtual Hosting the distinction is done via hostname (and port) instead of ip (and port). So you can point multiple hostnames on the same server ip and use those to access your services individually.

Answer (score 1):

You may assign different ip addresses to your nic(s). Each application should listen on different ip possibly with the same port.
Like 192.168.0.3:3000 and 192.168.0.4:3000.
For public service you need two public IP's.